# Does exterior product commute functor Hom?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra

Let $M$ be an module over the commutative ring $R$. I'd like to ask do we have the following isomorphism?

$$Hom_R(\wedge^n_RM,R)\simeq \wedge^n_R Hom_R(M,R)$$

We can obviously see it's true for the case $M=R^m$ is a free $R$-module.
But I don't know in general.

Comment: I strongly suspect that it's false even for infinite-dimensional vector spaces over fields. Did you check that?

Comment: @Alexader: it's flase for finite-dimesional vector spaces. So I would ask: $Hom_R(\wedge ^n_RN,R)\simeq \wedge^n_R Hom_R(N,R)$ ?

Comment: This does not pass the test of checking the case of free modules of finite rank. If $N$ has rank $a$ and $M$ has rank $b$, with $n \leq a$ then the left side has rank $\binom{a}{n}b$ and the right side has rank $\binom{ab}{n}$. While these are equal if $n = 1$ or $b = 1$, they are certainly not equal for most choices of $a$, $b$, and $n$.

Comment: @DinhVanHoang: if you want to change your question, you should edit it so people see what you want to ask in the question box rather than leave changes to your question in the comment section.

Comment: @DinhVanHoang: My comment still applies. For infinite-dimensional vector spaces, for instance, $\mathrm{Hom}(\wedge^2 M, R)$ consists of all skew-symmetric matrices, while $\wedge^2 \mathrm{Hom}(M, R)$ only contains those of finite rank.

Comment: The hom space you are asking about is actually just the dual of $M$. So you can rephrase your question as to whether taking a dual commutes with taking an exterior power. See a related question where the normal tensor power is dealt with: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/56255/duals-and-tensor-products